# Shuffle 2D Array By Row in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, shuffle

I want to shuffle 2D array row by row. For example,

```
arr = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}};
```

After shuffling, I need something like this:

```
arr = {{1,0},{1,1},{0,0},{0,1}};
```

I can do this my myself. But I wondered any standard functions are there?

Comment: Take a look at the [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), I'm sure you can find something there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`std::shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)  algorithm, like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  int arr[][2] = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 g(rd());

  std::shuffle(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), g);

  for(auto &row: arr)
    std::cout << row[0] << ',' << row[1] << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```